# bash sed replace from first ocurrence to right

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace

I am trying to obtain the first word before /

I am using following sed:

```
echo 'a/b/c' | sed 's/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

But this gives me `a/b`, I would like it to give me only `a`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
echo 'a/b/c' | sed 's,\([^/]*\)/.*,\1,'
```

*Details*:

- `\([^/]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Or, if you have a variable, you can use string manipulation:

```bash
s='a/b/c'
echo "${s%%/*}"
# => a
```

Here, `%%` removes the longest substring from the end, that matches the `/*` glob pattern, up to the first `/` in the string including it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily in `bash` itself without calling any external utility:

```bash
s='a/b/c'
echo "${s%%/*}"

a

# or else
echo "${s/\/*}"

a
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and an alternate delimiter to prevent a conflict with a similar char in the data.

```
$ echo 'a/b/c' | sed 's#/.*##'
a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` instead of `sed` to isolate char-separated fields for clarity, simplicity, and efficiency:

```
$ echo 'a/b/c' | cut -d'/' -f1
a

$ echo 'a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i' | cut -d'/' -f5
e
```